# Autoresize ScrollView on OrientationChange (react-native)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

is it possible to autoresize a scrollview when the orientation of the device changes ?

Tried to call the render () and forceUpdate () method within the orientationChange method but it didn't work. 
Any ideas ?